# Simulating signalR connection failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, websocket, signalr

I have a website hosted in IIS 8.5. It use signalR to send and receive messages from and to the browser. Periodically (3 seconds) the browser calls a server method called `Ping()` and I receive a response in the browser in a client method.

My server method is like this:

```
public void Ping()
{
    Clients.Caller.SendAck("OK");
}
```

All is working fine. But for testing purposes I'm simulating a connection failure by stopping the WebSite (not the IIS or the Application Pool). What is strange is even with the website stopped, the client method in the browser is called normally, as when the website was runnig. And the state of the connection is "connected" instead of disconnected.

In my debbuging process I tried to change the website port in the ISS. I was using port 80 and I changed it to port 83. Now, when I stop the website, the server method isn't called and the new state is disconnected, as expected.

So why port 80 has a different behavior than others? Is there any issue/limitation known about this?

**More details:**

- The signalR connection use websockets;
- IIS and browser are renning in the same machine;
- When I stop the Application Pool instead, the connection is lost as expected;

I could put more code but I don't think that the problem is in my code because when I change the port other than 80 the simulation works fine...